# Copying Data to another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I use two workbooks (obviously based on the question:)), from the first one (as you will see in the code below) gets sorted by the data in column "B". The data in this column is just a number based on the month (11=November, December=12, etc.). For this question (and it will provide the answer for my other monthly workbooks),  need to copy all the rows of data (columns A:AE) in column B to another workbook (which is already open), and paste the data into the empty row at the bottom. I have the sort part working fine. I am trying to add in the copy & paste function into the code, but can't get it to work. HELP!

Here is the code I have tried (but can't figure out how to get focus to the target workbook):

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1512_December()
' This line renames the worksheet to "Extract"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Extract"

' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

' This unhides any hidden rows
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Dim LR As Long

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:Z2000")
    .Apply
End With

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "12" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next LR

Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = “12” Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 31)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        ActiveWorkbook(“Master File - Swivel - December 2015.xlsm”).Select
        Worksheets(“Master”).Select
        erow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

        ActiveSheet.Cells(erow, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have found this code below, but do not know how to insert it properly into my code above. The thing that makes me weary is that the workbooks are already open. The target workbook is located on our SharePoint site and I do not know how (or if) you can use VBA code to open it to your desktop.

Here is the other code:

```
Sub Demo()

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbTarget As Workbook

    ' First open both workbooks :
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("  ") ' <<< path to source workbook
    Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook ' Workbooks.Open("  ") ' <<< path to destination workbook

    'Now, transfer values from wbSource to wbTarget:
    wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("H4")
    wbTarget.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("J10")

    'Close source:
    wbSource.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code slightly, but kept most of it as is.

I think the problem was related to the way in which you were trying to activate the workbook where the data was to be pasted.  Normally the `Activate` command is used with workbooks, as opposed to `Select`.  However, I bypassed the whole activation of the new workbook, because it would require you to then "re-activate" the original workbook before copying the next line.  Otherwise you would be copying from the active workbook, which would now be the one to be pasted into.  Please see the code - it should be fairly straightforward.

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1512_December()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' This line renames the worksheet to "Extract"
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Extract"

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

    ' This unhides any hidden rows
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Dim LR As Long

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange Range("A2:Z2000")
        .Apply
    End With

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Not Range("B" & LR).Value = "12" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next LR

    Cells.WrapText = False
    Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "12" Then

            ' As opposed to selecting the cells, I just copy them directly
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 31)).Copy

            ' As opposed to "Activating" the workbook, and selecting the sheet, I just paste the cells directly
            With Workbooks("Master File - Swivel - December 2015.xlsm").Sheets("Master")
                erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With

            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Demetri. This worked perfectly. But there is one thing, how can I force close the source workbook without having to perform a save? This is a temporary workbook that is created during the export from our reporting site. I should add that the name of this workbook is different each time we run an export. It uses a 27 digit time code as the name. Wish I could change that, but it is what it is...lol.

Comment: Adding `ActiveWorkbook.Close False` at the end will close the active workbook without saving it.  In this case, that should work.  It is important that the active workbook is in fact the one that is temporary, as it would not be good to close a different workbook, and that without saving it.